# Mono to Stereo using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, encoding

I have an unusual problem that I hope someone can help me solve.
I have 45 video files that I'm batch encoding as MP4.
Some of those files have their audio channel position set to Front L R and others have have it set to Front C.
However, the distribution system which these videos are sent to (and which I have no control over) does some re-processing of these videos.
All the videos that have their Channel Position set to Front C are coming back with distorted audio.

My question is:

Does anyone know how to encode a video with ffmpeg and force the audio channel positions to be Front L R?
(I have carefully studied this page (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#monostereo) but it was not obvious what the solution might be)

Thank you!

Comment: The encoder will set stereo layout when you encode with `-ac 2` as shown in the wiki you linked to.

Comment: @Mulvya Thank you, I tried your suggestion. After encoding ffmpeg reported the following for the audio information: "Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)" It's not clear to me how to read this. Does LC mean "Left Channel"?

Comment: No. LC means Low Complexity and refers to the audio bitstream profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run `ffmpeg -layouts`, you will see that stereo indicates the presence of two channels, one assigned as Front Left and the other as Front Right. If you use `-ac 2` in your encode, ffmpeg will create a stereo layout output by default. FFmpeg does not display the individual channel assignments in the readout of the file.